# Browser crashing with this template - endless looping?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I try to display a model tree structured collection. But evertime I run this, the browser crashes like there is a endless loop. But I don't see a mistake:

**collection**

```
{ "_id" : "7PAzgmcTfrcodKNYd", "title" : "Article" }
{
    "_id" : "ZnTn5pHT3GtHWqv4C",
    "title" : "Category 1",
    "parent" : "7PAzgmcTfrcodKNYd"
}
{
    "_id" : "u3zyuHegsokAoDrQX",
    "title" : "Element 1",
    "parent" : "j9WmezrM7pQvSq93c"
}
{
    "_id" : "Te7jhxv4aRoAFEkiv",
    "title" : "Element 2",
    "parent" : "ZnTn5pHT3GtHWqv4C"
}
{
    "_id" : "j9WmezrM7pQvSq93c",
    "title" : "Group",
    "parent" : "ZnTn5pHT3GtHWqv4C"
}
```

**template**

```
<template name="editor">
    {{#each section}}
        <div class="section">
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            {{>getElements}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="getElements">
    <ul>
        {{#each children _id}}
            <li>{{title}}
                {{#if hasChildren _id}}
                    {{>getElements parent=_id}}
                {{/if}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**helpers**

```
Template.getElements.helpers({
  children: function(parentId){
    return Articles.find({ parent: parentId });
  },
  hasChildren: function(id){
    return Articles.find({ parent: id }).count() > 0;
  }
});

Template.editor.helpers({
    section: function(){
        var articleId = Session.get('articleId');
        return Articles.find({ parent: articleId });
    }
});
```

I expect to get the result

```
<div class="section">
    <h2>Category 1</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Element1</li>
        <li>Group
            <ul>
                <li>Element 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`{{#if hasChildren _id}}` This _id should be the _id of the children elements, not of section elements. That should work, right?

Comment: "Like there is an endless loop" you mean the page freezes then says something like "script is not responding"?

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart Why not offer a Meteorpad?

Comment: @Kyll Here is a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ccTRc7dszJr4B34Xw/Meteor-Tree).

Comment: By the way, I think the `{{>getElements parent=_id}}` template call causes the endless loop, due to a wrong data context.

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart Could you explain it? I see, you did it without parameters... With that, it works. Thanks!